# How llibraries download medias from websites like facebook, twitch, etc?

Tags: python, web, download, request, media

I want to know how libraries like pytube, facebook-downloader, twitch-dl, etc download videos ?

In my case I use selenium, ffmpeg but for pytube i do not see any headless google, or i don't need to download ffmpeg to work with. The only ways I know to download actually is from url in the html code or from request_url but i need ffmpeg and selenium in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook: [Facebook-downloader](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-downloader/)

For Twitch: [Twitch-dl](https://pypi.org/project/twitch-dl/)

For YouTube: [Pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/)

You can find libraries for other websites at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).